# Lost in multitenant Windsor Castle configuration

Tags: c#, winforms, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, multi-tenant

I use Windsor Castle with `IHandlerSelector` for multitenant implementation.

I have two forms `FrmInvoice` and a custom `FrmInvoiceCustomer1` share same `IFrmInvoice` interface. I want to switch them with my selector class.

```
public interface IFrmInvoice
{
   void Show();
}

container.Kernel.AddHandlerSelector(
            new FrmInvoiceSelector(
                new Type[] { typeof(IFrmInvoice) }));
```

Forms are registered with this code:

```
 container.Register(AllTypes.FromThisAssembly()
                            .Pick()
                            .If(t => t.Name.StartsWith("Frm"))
                            .Configure((c => c.LifeStyle.Transient)));
```

I've my main form with a button with this code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IFrmInvoice form1 = formsFactory.CreateForm<IFrmInvoice>();
    form1.Show();
}
```

Now I ask: How I can register `IFrmInvoice` interface into the Windsor container? Is this the right way to do this?

**update**

I think I'm very close. In this way it works but it register all interfaces used by my classes! There's a better way?

```
 container.Register(AllTypes.FromAssemblyContaining<IFrmInvoice>()
              .BasedOn(typeof(IFrmInvoice)).WithService.AllInterfaces());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I've found a solution:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IFrmInvoice>().ImplementedBy<IFrmInvoice>());
```

Comment: Why is the implementation type an interface? And how is this related to the original question?

Comment: "How I can register IFrmInvoice interface"?

Comment: but you can't register an interface as implementation... if you can, it's a bug in Windsor.

Comment: very weird indeed! can you please post a test that uses this registration successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Use a Windsor Installer implementation, for example:

```
public class SampleInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Kernel.AddHandlerSelector(new InvoiceHandlerSelector());
    }

    public class InvoiceHandlerSelector: IHandlerSelector
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then install it:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer().Install(FromAssembly.InDirectory(new AssemblyFilter(...)));
```

Comment: My problem is not register the `HandlerSelector` but to register the shared interface `IFrmInvoice`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now I see.. we are registering in this way:

```
public class ComponentsInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        var allTypesFromBinDir = AllTypes.FromAssemblyInDirectory(new AssemblyFilter(HttpRuntime.BinDirectory));

        container.Register(allTypesFromBinDir
            .BasedOn<IComponentService>()
            .WithService.FromInterface());
    }
}
```